# Huygens principle (phase velocity)

Tags: waves, huygens-principle, phase-velocity

According to my physics book, the Huygens principle states that "given a wave front S at the instant of time t each point of this can be considered as a source of secondary spherical waves that propagate with the same phase velocity of the primary wave at the point under examination".

I'm not sure I understand what "at the point under examination" means. I guess it refers to the point, on the primary wave front S, in which the primary wave has the given phase velocity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can delete "at the point under examination".  It is not required.
Also you could replace "phase velocity" with "propagation velocity".  Then the statement would apply to most, or all, waves including pulses.
Re.

> I'm not sure I understand what "at the point under examination" means.
> I guess it refers to the point, on the primary wave front S, in which
> the primary wave has the given phase velocity.

I think he meant at an arbitrary point in space where you want to see the resulting wave.  Again, replace "phase" with "propagation".

Comment: Can you explain better "I think he meant at an arbitrary point in space where you want to see the resulting wave."?

Comment: I was referring to "at the point under examination"  For example, put a probe at that point and measure and record the passing waves as a function of time.